# Opencv Custom Compile

Tags: ios, opencv

I'm trying to reduce opencv2.framework size for ios. My project using only core,imgproc and highgui modules. How can I compile with only those modules? or is there an alternative for reducing size?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete modules from modules folder and remove include lines from headers file.And compile. Before doing that read CMakeLists.txt for dependencies.

For example, for highgui module;

```
ocv_define_module(imgproc opencv_core)
```

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this issue now with version 3.1, and nebuto's answer is close, but not complete as of now. The following was able to produce the desired result by updating the build_framework.py file.

```
def getCMakeArgs(self, arch, target):
    args = [
        "cmake",
        "-GXcode",
        "-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF",
        "-DBUILD_opencv_core=ON",
        "-DBUILD_opencv_imgcodecs=OFF",
        "-DBUILD_opencv_imgproc=ON",
        "-DBUILD_opencv_world=OFF",
        "-DBUILD_opencv_gpu=OFF",
        "-DBUILD_opencv_calib3d=OFF",
        "-DBUILD_opencv_contrib=OFF",
        "-DBUILD_opencv_features2D=OFF",
        "-DBUILD_opencv_flann=OFF",
        "-DBUILD_opencv_highgui=ON",
        "-DBUILD_opencv_legacy=OFF",
        "-DBUILD_opencv_ml=OFF",
        "-DBUILD_opencv_nonfree=OFF",
        "-DBUILD_opencv_objdetect=OFF",
        "-DBUILD_opencv_photo=OFF",
        "-DBUILD_opencv_stitching=OFF",
        "-DBUILD_opencv_video=OFF",
        "-DBUILD_opencv_videoio=OFF",
        "-DBUILD_opencv_videostab=OFF",
        "-DAPPLE_FRAMEWORK=ON",
        "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install",
        "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release",
    ]
    return args
```

This update also includes two new modules that appear to have not existed in 2.4.6.

For some additional savings, you can likely remove the i386 settings for simulator builds which is located at the bottom of the file. If your app is iOS 9 and above, and you wish to omit 32 bit devices, you can also take out the armv7 option as well.

```
b = Builder(args.opencv, args.contrib,
    [
        ("armv7", "iPhoneOS"),
        ("armv7s", "iPhoneOS"),
        ("arm64", "iPhoneOS"),
        #("i386", "iPhoneSimulator"),
        ("x86_64", "iPhoneSimulator"),
    ])
b.build(args.out)
```

Comment: opencv_world is not mandatory: http://answers.opencv.org/question/3614/what-is-opencv_world-package-in-opencv-243-rc/

Answer (score 3):

As of v2.4.6 OpenCV has a custom python script to ease the work
(plateforms > ios > build_framework.py)

You just need to add flags on the cmake line to make a custom compile.

For instance : I only needed the lib imgproc and to include all the headers into the archive, my cmake now ressembles this :

```
cmakeargs = ("-GXcode " +
            "-D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF "+
            "-D BUILD_opencv_core=ON "+
            "-D BUILD_opencv_imgproc=ON "+
            "-D BUILD_opencv_world=ON "+
            "-D BUILD_opencv_gpu=OFF "+
            "-D BUILD_opencv_calib3d=OFF "+
            "-D BUILD_opencv_contrib=OFF "+
            "-D BUILD_opencv_features2D=OFF "+
            "-D BUILD_opencv_flann=OFF "+
            "-D BUILD_opencv_highgui=OFF "+
            "-D BUILD_opencv_legacy=OFF "+
            "-D BUILD_opencv_ml=OFF "+
            "-D BUILD_opencv_nonfree=OFF "+
            "-D BUILD_opencv_objdetect=OFF "+
            "-D BUILD_opencv_photo=OFF "+
            "-D BUILD_opencv_stitching=OFF "+
            "-D BUILD_opencv_video=OFF "+
            "-D BUILD_opencv_videostab=OFF "+
            "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release " +
            "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=%s/platforms/ios/cmake/Toolchains/Toolchain-%s_Xcode.cmake " +
            "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install") % (srcroot, target)
```

Don't forget to **add the core and world lib** as they are obligatory.
Execute the python script > profite.

After that add the lib manually to your project and remove the pesky import headers left in the headers > opencv.hpp and you should be good to go !

Answer (score 2):

As of opencv 3.4.1, you can now use the `BUILD_LIST` arg to specify which modules to build. This is a white-list approach vs the black-list approaches using `-BUILD_opencv_xxx=OFF` approaches above.

If all you want is the `imgproc` module then you can modify the build script to something like this:

```
def getCMakeArgs(self, arch, target):
    args = [
        "cmake",
        "-GXcode",
        "-DBUILD_LIST=imgproc"
        "-DAPPLE_FRAMEWORK=ON",
        "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install",
        "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release",
    ]
    return args
```

Although in practice, this didn't quite work for me. I had to also manually exclude `highgui`, `imgcodecs`, and `videoio`:

```
def getCMakeArgs(self, arch, target):
    args = [
        "cmake",
        "-GXcode",
        "-DBUILD_LIST=imgproc"
        "-DBUILD_opencv_highgui=OFF",
        "-DBUILD_opencv_imgcodecs=OFF",
        "-DBUILD_opencv_videoio=OFF",
        "-DAPPLE_FRAMEWORK=ON",
        "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install",
        "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release",
    ]
    return args
```